# Eigenvalues of unitary matrices over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-fields, unitary-matrices

Let $q$ be a power of an odd prime number $p$. Let us fix $\overline{\mathbb F}$ an algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_q$ and let $\sigma$ denote the Frobenius relative to $q$. Consider the group of unitary matrices defined as
$$\mathrm{U}_n := \{M\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\overline{\mathbb F})\,|\, MM^* = I_n\}$$
where the conjugation $M^* := \,^t M ^{\sigma}$ is considered with respect to the $\sigma$-hermitian form
$$(X,Y) := \sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i^q$$
over $\overline{\mathbb F}^n$. Note that $\mathrm U_n \subset \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb F_{q^2})$.

> Given a matrix $M\in \mathrm U_n$, its determinant must be a $q+1$-th root of unity.
> Could the same be said of every eigenvalue of $M$ ?

As I consider an eigenvalue $\lambda \in \overline{\mathbb F}$ together with an eigenvector $X\in \overline{\mathbb F}^n$, I may write that
$$\lambda^{q+1}(X,X) = (\lambda X,\lambda X) = (MX, MX) = (X,X)$$
And sure enough, the eigenvalue would be a $q+1$-th root of unity if $(X,X) \not = 0$.

But what if $(X,X) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{q+1} = 0$ ?

If the eigenspace is of dimension at least $2$, we could expect that $X$ could be modified within this eigenspace so that $(X,X) \not = 0$. However, if the eigenspace is just a line, this can't be done.